# heterogenous treatment effects - a question

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, tobit-regression, heterogeneity

So I conducted a framing experiment - 4000 people received either framing A or B, and donated $ to a charity if they wanted to.
Now I want to check if framing A or B had specific efffects on covariates of my sample (I did randomized stratification on these).Lets call these covariates cov1 and cov2

My first approach was to restrict the sample to A and B, and run a left censored tobit and a logit for my analysis (Y is donation ammount for tobit, and Y is binary variable)

A second approach is just to control for framing A, then have cov1 cov2 cov1xA cov2xA, and both tobit and logit with same dependant variables

Both get "similar" intuitions, yet I believe the second approach allows me to say something about differences between A and B.  The issue is that the second approach also eats up a lot of my significance, I believe that is because I basically have small pool of people who donated, but I do wonder why.

Would running the first approach, and then use wald tests between coefficients help me in any way?